# How can I enable nested search sunspot solr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot

I have two models: `User` and `User_profile`

In User.rb, User `has_one :user_profile`.

In User_profile.rb, User_profile `belongs_to :user`.

Then I have users_controller and its index.html.erb.
So I added this to my User model in order to enable search by nested column, but it shows an error when I try to reindex. How can I fix this?

> undefined method `user_profiles' for #

models/user.rb

```
....
  searchable do 
    text :user_profile_nickname do
      user_profiles.map { |user_profile| user_profile.nickname }
    end
  end
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have given User `has_one :user_profile` in your user.rb file. So it can't be collection of objects, rather it is a member object. So you can not call `user_profiles.map { |user_profile| user_profile.nickname }` in your **User** model.

If you want to call write as following:

```
searchable do 
  text :user_profile_nickname do
    user_profile.nickname
  end
end
```

The above will work for sure. Do let me know if not working.